# Do not strip White spaces at the beginning or end of a text - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, trim, removing-whitespace

I have this code in Python that converts a decimal to its corresponding ASCII character.

```
import codecs
def convert_decimal_to_string(decrypted):
    decrypted = hex(decrypted)
    decrypted = decrypted.replace('0x', '')        
    return codecs.decode(codecs.decode(decrypted,'hex'),'ascii')

decrypted = 1612388154947973357665
decrypted = convert_decimal_to_string(decrypted)
print(decrypted + 'Creel?')
```

The output should be "What is a Creel?" not "What is aCreel" . How will I keep the blank spaces at the beginning or end of my text?

Comment: Your input is wrong: `>>> '\x57\x68\x61\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61'
'What is a'`. the code cannot make up a space that isn't there.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta --> thank you, there must be something wrong somewhere in my code. I'll update it later.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta --> You can put your comment in the answer section so that I can mark it as the correct answer. I have solve my problem already. Your idea got me searching to the another part of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input lacks the space at the end:

```
>>> hex(1612388154947973357665)
'0x576861742069732061'
>>> # manually add \x for every pair of digits:
>>> '\x57\x68\x61\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61'
'What is a'
```